# how to get catkin package recognized by rosrun

Tags: ros, catkin, package, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a catkin workspace folder ~/catkin-ws, and downloaded usb_cam (http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) source into ~/catkin-ws/src. I called catkin_make and ~/catkin-ws/devel/lib/usb_cam/usb_cam_node is created.

But when I type rosrun usb[TAB Key],  nothing happened.

I think this is because usb_cam not registered to ros system yet, since there is no usb_cam in /opt/ros/hydro/lib(I am using hydro). so I tried this:

sudo cp -r ~/catkin-ws/devel/lib/* /opt/ros/hydro/lib/

still not working. how to get a catkin complied package recognized by rosrun?

by the way, running "~/catkin-ws/devel/lib/usb_cam/usb_cam_node" directly does work. is that the correct way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156881/how-to-get-catkin-package-recognized-by-rosrun/) by [vdonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/14946/vdonkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-23**:
There are some articles about usb_cam in ROS Q&A.
For example, check it out (http://answers.ros.org/question/42906/issue-with-usb_cam-cant-open-camera/) .

**Comment by [vdonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/14946/vdonkey/) on 2014-04-23**:
Thanks, Ken. It works, you are great. I know cp and run node directly without rosrun can hardly be a good answer, but I just cannot find the correct one after reading tutorials and ppt courses by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try this command `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` after compiling the package? I always execute the command to make PC recognize the package. `sudo cp -r ~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/* /opt/ros/hydro/lib/`  is bad. I think that this behaivior isn't described on wiki.ros.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3